# Why is jQuery UI autocomplete returning as disabled/"off"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am trying to enable jQuery UI's autocomplete, however, each time I console the element, it shows that it's disabled or "off".  Why would it be doing this?

**HTML**
`<input type="text" id="contactName">`

**JS**

Using the "enable" string

```
$("#contactName").autocomplete({
    source: searchableNames
}, "enable")
```

Using the "on" string

```
$("#contactName").autocomplete({
    source: searchableNames
}, "on")
```

Setting the option

```
$("#contactName").autocomplete({
    disabled: false,
    source: searchableNames
})
```

Results

```
<input type="text" id="contactName" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
```

Can anyone explain why it's remaining disabled and how I can fix it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following script to reset autocomplete attribute:

```
$("#contactName").removeAttr("autocomplete").attr("autocomplete", "On");
```

Comment: That worked, but why did I need to reset the attribute?

Comment: Isn't the default for the autocomplete method enabled though?

Comment: By default it is on if you do not mention autocomplete atribute in your input tag.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Thanks for explaining.